# NotifyPropertyChanged attribute produces compiler error

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light, inotifypropertychanged, postsharp

I implemented Postharp into my existing project made with MVVM-Light. I defined my properties in the viewmodel as following:

```
public WindowState WindowState
{
    get
    {
        return windowState;
    }

    set
    {
        if(windowState != value)
        {
            windowState = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("WindowState");
        }
    }
}
```

I implemented PostSharp's `NotifyPropertyChanged` attribute:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public WindowState WindowState { get; private set; }
}
```

Now I get this compile error when starting the program:

`Class ViewModels.MainViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged but does not define an OnPropertyChanged method with the following signature: void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)`

Do I have to implement such a method into my viewmodel or even into an overriden ViewModelBase?

Comment: Yes.  When you inherit a class it often is required to implement methods that are associated with the inherited class.  The change event is needed in this case to notify the Window Paint method to update the window with new data.  See : https://www.postsharp.net/model/inotifypropertychanged

Comment: Well for me this is the difference of "Massive code reduction.". Could I implement this method override into a base class inheriting from ViewModelBase? I want to keep such methods out of my ViewModel implementation.

Comment: Yes, or another partial class in a different .cs module.

Comment: I just excluded ViewModelBase and it works fine. Is this the right solution?

Comment: I don't know.  If the windows is getting updated when changes are made then I guess it is OK.  If updates aren't getting changed in the window then it is not OK.

Comment: Then I guess it's ok

Answer (score 0):

Apply the attribute `[NotifyPropertyChanged]` to the class `ViewModelBase` only. It will get to the descendant classes through inheritance.